# How do you make `git grep` output look like `ack` output?

Tags: git, grep, ack

I've recently found `git grep` and come to like its speed and de facto searching of only the files in the repo. But coming from `ack` (`ack-grep` in Ubuntu), one thing left to be desired is the output formatting, which is unfortunately much more like `grep` than `ack`. Go figure.

***`ack`***:

1. Prints the **matching filename on** the **first line** by itself.
2. Color highlights the **matching filename** a **bold green**.
3. **Prints** the line number, and **only** the **line number**, with **each matching line**.
4. Color highlights the **line number** a **bold yellow**.
5. Color highlights each **matching string** a **background yellow**.
6. Prints a **blank line** between matches from different files.

*On the other hand, **`git grep`**:*

- Prints the **filename** on **every** matching **line**.
- Prints **no line number**.
- Prints **no blank line** between matches from different files.
- Color highlights **only** the **matching text**, a **bold red**.

Is there any set of `git grep` options, or combo with other tools, that can make `git grep` output look like `ack` output?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You've already answered part of your own question (`--break` inserts a blank line between files, `--heading` prints the file name separately, and `-n` or `--line-number` gives you line numbers on each line).

The rest is just color options, which are [set in `git config`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) via the `color.grep.<slot>` entries.  See the documentation for full details, but note that based on what you asked for, I think this does the trick:

```
[alias]
    ack = -c color.grep.linenumber=\"bold yellow\" \
          -c color.grep.filename=\"bold green\" \
          -c color.grep.match=\"reverse yellow\" \
          grep --break --heading --line-number
```

(this is expressed as you'd see it in `git config --global --edit` since the quoting is messy).

Or, to set it up in one command:

```
git config --global alias.ack '-c color.grep.linenumber="bold yellow"
    -c color.grep.filename="bold green"
    -c color.grep.match="reverse yellow"
    grep --break --heading --line-number'
```

Add or subtract `-c` options to change whatever colors you like, and/or set them to your preferred defaults by setting `color.grep.<name> = color` instead of using the `git ack` alias.

Comment: Perhaps `ack` would be a better alias name for this.

Answer (score 5):

From [Travis Jeffery](http://travisjeffery.com/b/2012/02/search-a-git-repo-like-a-ninja/), to **group** `git grep` output like `ack`:

```
git config --global alias.g "grep --break --heading --line-number"
```

And then use `git g` like you would `git grep`:

```
git g <search_string>
```

This is not a complete match to `ack` output -- it's missing the color highlighting -- but for a quick solution it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

With [this patch](https://marc.info/?l=git&m=159048225626936&w=2) applied, almost everything can be done with Git configuration:

```
git config --global color.grep.linenumber "bold yellow"
git config --global color.grep.filename "bold green"
git config --global color.grep.match "reverse yellow"
git config --global grep.linenumber true
git config --global grep.heading true
```

(The missing bit is a configuration option for `--break`.)